# Piwik determine if mobile or computer user

Tags: matomo

My question is concerned whether you can determine in piwik if a user browses through your website/webpage using either a mobile device or on a computer. If so how do you go about this? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [online demo](http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday#module=UserSettings&action=index&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday) (you may want to change the language setting towards the top right), you can see which OS your users use under 'Visitors'->'Settings'->'Operating System'. Android, iPhone, iPad, iPod, Windows Phone OS, Symbian and Windows Mobile are all listed.